# Address of First Vowel of a String in C - What is wrong with this?

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* First_Vowel(char *s);

int main()
{

  char* s = NULL;
  printf("Insert a string: ");
  fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
  printf("\nThe memory address of the first vowel is %s\n", First_Vowel(s));

  return 0;

}

char *First_Vowel(char *s)
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
      {
       if(s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'E' || s[i] 
       == 'i' 
       || s[i] == 'I' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'O' || s[i] == 'u' || s[i] 
       == 'U')
          return &s[i];
      }
   return NULL;
}
```

It gives a segmentation fault after I enter a string, with no compiling errors. If there is no vowel, the First_Vowel function returns NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate some memory to `s` that would save you from Undefined behavior.

```
s =malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
if(s==NULL)
  // error

..
free(s);
s=NULL;
```

Whenever you `malloc` something don't forget to `free` it.
Also in the for loop `s[i]!='\0'` will be the correct one.

#### code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
char* First_Vowel(char *s);

int main()
{

  char* s = NULL;
  printf("Insert a string: ");
  s=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
  if( s == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n","Error in malloc" );
    exit(1);
  }
  fgets(s, 100 , stdin);

  printf("\nThe memory address of the first vowel is %p\n", First_Vowel(s)); // `%p` will save you from blowing up in case this is NULL

  return 0;

}

char *First_Vowel(char *s)
{
   int i;
   for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
      {
       if(s[i] == 'a' || s[i] == 'A' || s[i] == 'e' || s[i] == 'E' || s[i] 
       == 'i' 
       || s[i] == 'I' || s[i] == 'o' || s[i] == 'O' || s[i] == 'u' || s[i] 
       == 'U')
          return &s[i];
      }
   return NULL;
}
```

Or you can do this thing also:-(why is this suggested? ) Because if the function returns `NULL` then you will try to dereference it and it will blow things up.

```
char* temp = First_Vowel(s);
if( temp == NULL)
  printf("%s","It is not found");
else
  printf("\nThe memory address of the first vowel is %s\n", s);
```

Comment: Dynamic allocation is probably unnecessary, but `sizeof(char)`  is always 1 by definition, so unnecessary.  Moreover you have duplicated the `sizeof(s)` error in the `fgets()` call.  `sizeof(s)` will work if `s` is declared as an array rather than needlessly dynamically allocated.  You also forgot to `free()` the allocation (another reason why it is ill-advised.

Comment: @Clifford.: Yes..modified..please check once.and thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) three problems:

1. Your `fgets()` call writes to `s` which does not refer to a valid data space. Moreover `sizeof(s)` in this case is the size of the pointer `s` not the size of the buffer (because you have none):

   ```
   char s[128] ;
   printf("Insert a string: ");
   fgets(s, sizeof(s), stdin);
   ```
2. You aim to print an address, but you are using the `%s` string format specifier, forcing `printf()` to de-reference a null pointer.  Use the `%p` format specifier.

   ```
   printf("\nThe memory address of the first vowel is %p\n", First_Vowel(s));
   ```
3. Your loop in `First_Vowel()` tests the index for equality or `\0`, when it should be testing `s[i]`.  The loop will terminate immediately because `0 == '\0'`.

   Beyond that, a simpler method of finding the first vowel would be to to use the standard library `strpbrk()`:

   ```
   printf( "\nThe memory address of the first vowel is %p\n", 
           strpbrk( s, "aeiouAEIOU") ) ;
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory to pointer `s` in `main()` before calling `fgets()`:

```
s = malloc (sizeof(char) * 1024);
```

or you can also do:

```
char s[1024] = {'\0'};
```

If you opt to all allocate memory dynamically (malloc) to `s` then make sure to replace `sizeof(s)` with the memory size allocated to `s` in `fgets()`, like this:

```
fgets(s, 1024, stdin);
```

You need to fix one more problem in your code.
In the function `First_Vowel()`, the `for` loop condition is incorrect:

```
for(i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
```

Here you are checking `i != '\0'` but you shoud check `s[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: For the first suggestion (malloc), `sizeof(s)` remains incorrect in the `fgets()` call.